# Using Ace to edit XML with XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, ace-editor

It is possible to use the Ace editor to edit XML according to a specified XSD?

If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact possible to validate **XSD** with **Ace**, it is just not supported by the libraries **Ace** comes with, so you will need to use something else to validate your **XML** against an **XSD** file. Then, you simply convert the error output you receive as annotations, and disable the default syntax validator using:

```
editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
```

For example, I am using [AgeGWT](https://github.com/daveho/AceGWT) which is a wrapper that allows usage of Ace inside Java and GWT. Note that the github version has very outdated libraries (3-4 years..maybe they will be updated in the future, but doesn't look like the page is actively maintained), so I simply downloaded and setup **Ace** using **npm** so that I can copy over and use **Ace**'s newest libraries (which have extra features).

Then, I used a Java XML validator that returns all errors, similar to that found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131662/how-to-validate-xml-against-xsd-and-get-all-errors).

This will retrieve a List/Array of **SAXParseException**. This type allows querying for the error text and line and column numbers - which is the minimum information required to set the annotations (I set them all to have the **Error Annotation** type).

The annotations themselves are set up on an Ace Callback, that is triggered each time the text in the editor is changed:

> ```
>   editor.addOnChangeHandler(new AceEditorCallback() {
>         @Override
>         public void invokeAceCallback(JavaScriptObject obj) {
>             // validate XSD...
> ```

Then I set the annotations in the **Ace Editor**, using the information gathered *previously* by the **validator**.

You do not have to use **Java**, or the specified libraries to make this work. There should be no issue doing this in **JavaScript** in a similar fashion, perhaps using [sax js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sax)...in fact, it will probably be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not, according to this 2013 [google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ace-discuss/SyAcnZnrs0Y)

CodeMirror is another JS editor that has an XML Hint capability. See [Demo](https://codemirror.net/demo/xmlcomplete.html). The schema can be customised.

There are several desktop alternatives with full validation capabilities.
See [O'Reilly Picking an XML Editor](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000058/ch01.html).

Comment: This is not true. It is possible to setup a schema validator alongside with Ace, please see my answer.