# Java - How to catch all exceptions/errors from xml validating file

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I woudlike to get all errors from my validating xml. Actually my method stop after catch the first error :

```
public List<String> validation(File file) {
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        List<String> statut = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            assert xsd != null;
            Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(xsd);
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(file.getPath() + file.getname())));
            statut.add(file.getname() + " is valid");

        } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
            statut.add(file.getname() + " not valid :\n");
            statut.add(e.getMessage());
        }
        return statut;
    }
```

How can I get all exception detected ?

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131662/how-to-validate-xml-against-xsd-and-get-all-errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Validator.setErrorHandler(ErrorHandler)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html#setErrorHandler(org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler)) to register your own error handler.

> `public abstract void setErrorHandler(ErrorHandler errorHandler)`
>
> Sets the `ErrorHandler` to receive errors encountered during the `validate` method invocation.
> Error handler can be used to customize the error handling process during a validation. When an `ErrorHandler` is set, errors found during the validation will be first sent to the ErrorHandler.
>
> The error handler can abort further validation immediately by throwing `SAXException` from the handler. Or for example it can print an error to the screen and try to continue the validation by returning normally from the `ErrorHandler`
>
> If any `Throwable` is thrown from an `ErrorHandler`, the caller of the validate method will be thrown the same `Throwable` object.
>
> Validator is not allowed to throw `SAXException` without first reporting it to `ErrorHandler`.

In your own error handler, you can aggregate the exceptions and then after validation, process as needed/wanted.

Specifically, it allows you to continue validation if errors are encountered enabling you to catch them all in the handler.